# paypal send custom field with express checkout

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk

I want to send a custom field in paypal's express checkout so I can receive the same when the IPN is sent back from paypal. This is not clearly defined in the documentation and am stuck here. here is my code:

```
 paypal.Button.render({

                env: 'production', // sandbox | production

                // PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
                // Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create
                client: {
                    sandbox:    'my sandbox client ID here',
                    production: 'my client ID here'
                },

                // Show the buyer a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow
                commit: true,

                // payment() is called when the button is clicked
                payment: function(data, actions) {

                    // Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
                    return actions.payment.create({
                        payment: {
                            transactions: [
                                {
                                    amount: { total: '1', currency: 'GBP' }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    });
                },

                // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
                onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

                    // Make a call to the REST api to execute the payment
                    return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                        console.log(data);

                        //my action here

                    });
                }

            }, '#paypal-button-container');
```

I can only send the amount and currency but can't figure out how to send the custom field.

Comment: what custom fields you want to send ?

Comment: You can use PAYMENTREQUEST_n_CUSTOM field to send your custom data.

Comment: @Himanshu Upadhyay i want to send user_id of the currently logged in person

Comment: @sonam gupta where exactly do i put that?

Comment: under your transactions array like this:
transactions: [
                {
                    amount: {
                        total:    total,
                        currency: 'USD'
                    },
                    custom: purchaseOrderNumber
                }
            ]

Comment: @sonamgupta i still dont get the custom variable when then IPN is sent even after doing that